# find the partial derivative of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $z^2=x^2+y^2$ find $z_x$ at $(x,y,z)=(3,4,5).$

This is how I went about the problem, but I don't think it's right.

$z^2=x^2+y^2 \Longrightarrow f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^2$ so $f_x(x,y,z)=2x$ and $f_x(3,4,5)=6.$

Again, I don't think this is right because I didn't make use of the $4$ or $5$ anywhere.

Comment: $z$ isn't a function, how can you find $z_x$?

Comment: I'm curious to know myself... that's the way the question was written.

Comment: Then there's no point in this question, is it?

Comment: This is just the implicit differentiation that you’re probably familiar with from single-variable calculus with an extraneous variable thrown in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are dealing with $P=(3,4,5)$, we have that

$$z^2=x^2+y^2 \implies z(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

and then

$$z_x(x,y)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\implies z_x(3,4)=\frac35$$

Comment: That's just adaptation to the question, but if it's stated in a wrong way, then giving an answer is just lying

Comment: @Adam At first I also thought it was meaningless but in that way it makes sense.

Comment: @Adam Indeed given the point $(3,4,5)$ allows to define $z=z(x,y)$ and then to evaluate $z_x$.

Comment: What if, $z(x, y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $x\leq 3$, and $z(x, y)=-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for $x>3$? It still doesn't make sense, you just try to make sense out of it

Comment: @Adam $z^2=x^2+y^2$ is a cone and once we declare that we are considering the point $(3,4,5)$ we can consider the upper part $z=+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ which is a function and then evaluate $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$. It seems really clear to me, even if the OP was not posed in the most clear way.

Comment: @Adam You must’ve had a hard time with implicit differentiation in Calc 1, too.

Comment: @amd Yes of course we can also obtain that by $2zz_x=2x\implies z_x=\frac x z = \frac 3 5$, good point!

Comment: @amd If the question would be asked a little different, there wouldn't be any problem. I'm just commenting that some people adjust to the question, not paying attention if it makes sense.

Comment: @Adam You should address your complaints about the question to the person asking the question, then, not to people who take their time to try to understand and answer it. Your initial comment here can easily be read as trolling.

Comment: @amd if the question is wrong, then the answer to the wrong question is wrong as well

Comment: @Adam It is nice and very useful have different point of views on that, what is inelegant from you is to accuse me to be a liar solely because I've given my own intepretation for the OP. But apart from that your one is a respectable point of view.